# Why do I get no line numbers from a stack trace created from Exceptions?

Tags: .net, debugging, stack-trace, line-numbers

Okay; assuming this code running in debug mode -

```
static StackFrame GetTopFrameWithLineNumber(Exception e)
{
    StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(e);
    foreach (StackFrame frame in trace.GetFrames())
    {
        if (frame.GetFileLineNumber() != 0)
        {
            return frame;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm ALWAYS returning null.  Why do the stack frames have no line numbers when if I inspect the `Exception.StackTrace` string, it clearly does have them for any non-framework code?  Is there some issue with constructing a stack trace from an exception that i'm not aware of?

**EDIT FOR CLARITY:**
In the thrown exception I can see the line numbers in the StackTrace property.  I'm assuming that means I have everything else I need.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [documentation on the StackTrace constructor overload that takes an exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25h0kw08.aspx) you can't expect line numbers when creating the StackTrace that way.

> The StackTrace is created with the
>   caller's current thread, and does not
>   contain file name, line number, or
>   column information.

**To get the line numbers**, you need to use [the overload that takes a bool as well as the exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsay49kt.aspx).

You also need symbol files (pdb) for line numbers. Symbol files are available for *both* debug and release builds.

Comment: Since I can see the line numbers in the exception.stacktrace string though doesn't that mean that i do have the pdb?

Comment: I don't think this is a case of missing pdb since he's able to see the line numbers.

Comment: Thinking about this, wouldn't it be better to make the standard StackFrame interface abstract and have a subclass (FileInfoStackFrame for example) which exposes the file information rather than have an overloaded constructor decide when those properties are appropriate?  Seems like a poorly defined interface to me.  Hmmm...